# How do you listen for multiple field changes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code to update a URL. How do I combine this into something more robust so that I'm not repeating myself 3 times basically. I only want this to update when one of the fields is changed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#device_select').change(function() {
      var device = $(this).val();
      var face = $('#face_select').val();
      var position = $('#position_select').val();
      document.getElementById("add_dev_rack").href="127.0.0.1:8080/dcim/devices/"+device+"/edit/?face="+face+"&position="+position;
  });
  $('#face_select').change(function() {
      var device = $('#device_select').val();
      var face = $(this).val();
      var position = $('#position_select').val();
      document.getElementById("add_dev_rack").href="127.0.0.1:8080/dcim/devices/"+device+"/edit/?face="+face+"&position="+position;
  });
  $('#position_select').change(function() {
      var device = $('#device_select').val();
      var face = $('#face_select').val();
      var position = $(this).val();
      document.getElementById("add_dev_rack").href="127.0.0.1:8080/dcim/devices/"+device+"/edit/?face="+face+"&position="+position;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not encapsulate your code in a function?

```
function updateURL() {
  var device = $('#device_select').val();
  var face = $('#face_select').val();
  var position = $('#position_select').val();
  document.getElementById("add_dev_rack").href="127.0.0.1:8080/dcim/devices/"+device+"/edit/?face="+face+"&position="+position;
}
```

You can then call the function anytime you want :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#device_select').change(updateURL);
  $('#face_select').change(updateURL);
  $('#position_select').change(updateURL);
});
```

Even better, you could add a second function so your code is more readable :

```
function listenForChanges(){
  $('#device_select').change(updateURL);
  $('#face_select').change(updateURL);
  $('#position_select').change(updateURL);
}
```

And call this function on `document.ready` :

```
$(document).ready(listenForChanges);
```

Comment: Perfection for my scenerio. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#position_select, #device_select, #face_select').change(function() {
      var device = $('#device_select').val();
      var face = $('#face_select').val();
      var position = $('#position_select').val();
      document.getElementById("add_dev_rack").href="127.0.0.1:8080/dcim/devices/"+device+"/edit/?face="+face+"&position="+position;
  });
```

Have you tried somethign like this?

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        ['#position_select',  '#device_select',  '#face_select'].forEach(
            function(ev){
                $(ev).change(function() {
                    var device = $('#device_select').val();
                    var face = $('#face_select').val();
                    var position = $('#position_select').val();
                    document.getElementById("add_dev_rack").href="127.0.0.1:8080/dcim/devices/"+device+"/edit/?face="+face+"&position="+position;
                });
            }
        )
    }
    )
```